# Break Line on TextArea

Tags: java, mysql, string, replace, newline

I have `Text\n Text` stored in the database.
When I select the text and put in on the Text Area, it doesn't show a new line. Instead, it shows `\n`.

I already tested with .`replaceAll` to replace `\\n` to `\n` and still nothing.
How to fix it?

My code:

```
            rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sobre WHERE codsobre = 0");
            String old;
            while (rs.next()) {
                old = rs.getString("texto");
                String nova = old.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
                TextArea.append(nova);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String nova = old.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference with new line characters between various OS out there. You could try

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

to get the new line character for the specific OS it is running on. Then replace the current new line character (`\\n`) with that character.

It's basically the same with other's answers, but I am trying to be clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Try: 
1) String nova = old.replaceAll("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

or

2) U can do a split then append the line.separator between each item